# JS: Find largest number in array of objects

Tags: javascript

What's the easiest way to find the largest number in an array of objects and return that object?

```
var arr = [ { num: 0.5 }, { num: 1 }, { num: 0.35 }]
```

Tried to use forEach but couldn't work out a way to do this, other than storing every number and comparing them.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Brute force would be easy

Comment: You don't store *every* number, you just loop through exactly once and keep a reference to whichever one is the current largest. Although you do need to think about what to do if more than one element has the same high number.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*reduce* will do the job:

```
var maxObj = arr.reduce(function(max, obj) {
  return obj.num > max.num? obj : max;
});
```

Comment: Reduce is what I was looking for.Thanks for this. Really elegant way to achieve the solution to my problem,

Answer (score 2):

returns the object with the largest number:

```
var arr = [ { num: 0.5 }, { num: 1 }, { num: 0.35 }]
var res = Math.max.apply(Math,arr.map(function(o){return o.num;}))
var obj = arr.find(function(o){ return o.num == res; })
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash?

```
   var arr = [ { num: 0.5 }, { num: 1 }, { num: 0.35 }]
   var max = _.max(arr, function(item) {
      return item.num;
   });
```

per aquinas suggestion - switched _.sortBy with _.max (there is no _.maxBy anymore)
plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/TYIou2GUUxRWcXoCXHnv?p=preview

Comment: Ack. Don't *sort* to find the largest number. If you are going to use lodash at all use maxby. `_.maxBy(arr,"num")`

Comment: @aquinas good point O(NlogN) is worse than O(N) - btw there is no _.maxBy anymore.. _.max is doing what is needed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Math.max()`, `JSON.stringify()` , `String.prototype.match()`

```
var arr = [ { num: 0.5 }, { num: 1 }, { num: 0.35 }];
var res = arr[(m = Math.max.apply(Math, n = JSON.stringify(arr).match(/(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)/g))) && n.indexOf(m+"")];
```

Comment: But that doesn't return an object. OP wants to get the object with the Max value, not just the value.

Comment: @nnnnnn _"But that doesn't return an object."_ ? Yes, it does; see bracket notation at `res = arr[/* Math.max() */]`

Comment: Maybe I'm just being particularly dense today, but aren't you trying to use the maximum .num property as an index into the original array? That won't work.

Comment: The "bit in brackets" returns the max value, that is then used as an index to the original array. It  "works" because in the OP, the max value is 1 and the related object is at index 1. Make the max value say 3 at index 0 and see what happens.

Comment: @RobG Yes, currently adjusting

Comment: @nnnnnn See updated post. Still trying to shorten further

Comment: @nnnnnn Of course, approach using `JSON.stringify()` , `.match()` would not return expected results if there were multiple properties having a number value in each object and only a single property was to be compared, without further filtering

Comment: @nnnnnn See updated post; was able to utilize original attempted approach of using `arr[/*index*/]`

Comment: @RobG Was able to use `arr[/*index*/]` approach, see updated post

Comment: Well, I guess you beat it into submission eventually. ;-) Not sure *JSON.stringify* is a sensible approach, and in `/(\d+.\d+)|(\d+)/g`  the period should be quoted.

Comment: @RobG Tried:) Though not entirely comfortable with `RegExp` and have a sense that it could be shortened further

Comment: @RobG Updated post to escape `.` at `RegExp`. Concur on using `JSON.stringify()` , actually also `.indexOf()` ; will continue to adjust as able to while attempting to maintain same or similar approach. Your `.reduce()` solution is certainly more viable and less chance of unexpected results